# How to navigate though xml nodes?

Tags: c#, xml

I have two buttons and three labels in a windows form and a xml file.

this is my xml:

```
<Qustions>
  <Question id="1" Cat="5">
    "Question Text 1"
  </Question>
  <Question id="2" Cat="2">
    "Question Text 2"
  </Question>
  <Question id="3" Cat="3">
    "Question Text 3"
  </Question>
  <Question id="4" Cat="5">
    "Question Text 4"
  </Question>
  <Question id="5" Cat="8">
    "Question Text 5"
  </Question>
</Qustions>
```

I want to show every question body and category in my form and navigate through them by buttons.

[image: This is my form]

which way is the best approach to achieve this?

Comment: This is a bit broad, to be honest - you need to parse the XML, probably transform it to some `Question` object, then implement something to navigate through them and bind the content to the UI  What have you tried? Have you got a *specific* problem?

Comment: Does Xml is a good way to save data for this purpose at all? or there is a better way to achive this. I also need to record results of test of persons. I chose the xml because the number of questions and the persons is under 100. do I need to use sql db?

Comment: Add some `demo code` .. we r not going to write full code for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code which uses XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int questionIndex = 0;
        public List<XElement> questions = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            string xml =
                "<Qustions>" +
                  "<Question id=\"1\" Cat=\"5\">" +
                    "\"Question Text 1\"" +
                  "</Question>" +
                  "<Question id=\"2\" Cat=\"2\">" +
                    "\"Question Text 2\"" +
                  "</Question>" +
                  "<Question id=\"3\" Cat=\"3\">" +
                    "\"Question Text 3\"" +
                  "</Question>" +
                  "<Question id=\"4\" Cat=\"5\">" +
                    "\"Question Text 4\"" +
                  "</Question>" +
                  "<Question id=\"5\" Cat=\"8\">" +
                    "\"Question Text 5\"" +
                  "</Question>" +
                "</Qustions>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            questions = doc.Descendants("Question").ToList();
            DisplayQuestion(questionIndex);

        }

        private void buttonPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (questionIndex != 0)
            {
                DisplayQuestion(--questionIndex);
            }
        }

        private void buttonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (questionIndex < questions.Count - 1)
            {
                DisplayQuestion(++questionIndex);
            }

        }
        public void DisplayQuestion(int index)
        {
            textBoxId.Text = questions[index].Attribute("id").Value;
            textBoxCat.Text = questions[index].Attribute("Cat").Value;
            textBoxCatText.Text = questions[index].Value;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try Linq,
I always use linq for navigate through xml nodes and attributes

Here's the link [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx)